# Installing Visual Studio through ansible with the win_chocolatey module ignores version and package parameters

Tags: ansible, chocolatey

When I try to install Visual studio 17.2 through ansible using the win_chocolatey module, it instead installs 17.8 Here is my ansible step. The version is intentionally 117 because thats how its listed in the chocolatey package.

```
- name: Install Visual Studio
win_chocolatey:
  name: visualstudio2022enterprise
  state: downgrade
  pinned: true
  version: '117.2.2.0'
  package_params: --channelUri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release.ltsc.17.2/channel
```

This works with the command choco install visualstudio2022enterprise --channelUri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release.ltsc.17.2/channel

that command does install the correct version.

Comment: Three questions - 1. What troubleshooting have you done? 2. Have you reached out to the maintainer? They have the best understanding of how the package works. 3. Have you tried this outside of the Ansible Collection to see if it works there?

My understanding (which could be wrong) is that VS Studio always installs the latest version for open-source as that's the only installer available. The Licensed version of Chocolatey CLI will cache many installer so that they can be used for historical versions. Looking at the package code it _may_ ignore the `--channeluri` value.

Comment: @pauby I edited my post to include this information, but I have tried running the choco command directly and it does work as intended. Additional troubleshooting I've done has been mainly messing with the syntax of the ansible command. nothing has given me different results.

Comment: So it definitely has to do with how I'm calling the params. looked into the logs and they say the channel ansible is using is `https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/channel`

Comment: Just to be clear, you've solved this?